# I can't solve the problem using Regular expressions

Tags: javascript

I have a task and I can't solve it (i.e. do it): A string is given, for example '011125228'. Delete the first, sixth and last characters from it.
In the resulting string, check that the sum of the first three digits equals the sum of the second three digits.
If so, output 'yes', otherwise output 'no'.

My beginning of this code:

```
var str = '011125228'
var y = str.replace (/^.|.$/g ,'')
var s = y.replace(y[6])
console.log (s)
```

I'm beginner in coding, pls help me!!!

Thanks for earlier

I want to shorten and finish this task. And also solve the problem with this code (

Comment: regular expressions is not the best way to solve this problem. Convert your string to an array (`array=[...string]`) and manipulate it as required.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use regex for something as simple as this. Regex is extremely powerful but also extremely difficult to read, if you are doing something as simple as this there is probably a built in function in js that can do it. In your case you want to use `str.substring(N)`
I assume you need an output of `22` within the input of `011125228` in this case your code will look something like this.

```js
let str = '011125228'
let newStr = str.substring(6, str.length - 1)
```

I hope you can code in if statements yourself.

P.S. Please try to avoid `var` they can be useful in rare cases but in most they cause unnecessary variable scope pollution.